# Triggering AJAX with an autonomous jQuery event

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have a question about how AJAX works, and what is needed to trigger a page load through it.

I want to have a separate page load in an iframe when a slideshow event called "vegaswalk" triggers:

The slideshow tools I'm using are a part of the vegas fullscreen slideshow; it can be downloaded from the makers site here [ http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/ ] if you'd like to play with it. The event is built in to the jQuery already- info is under the documentation-->slideshow path on the creator site.

Is this even possible? This is more a conceptual question rather than me asking for an example, but by all means if you want to write example code go ahead (I have close to zero experience attempting something like this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From vegas slideshow:

```
$('body').bind('vegaswalk',
  function(e, bg, step) {
    alert( 'N°' +step+ ' is now displayed' );
  }
);
```

That's how you detect when the slideshow changes. Then you can just set the `src` attribute on your iframe. I don't think you really want to use AJAX if you're displaying the page in an iframe you will basically (not *exactly*) achieve the same result as making an AJAX request and displaying the contents in a div.

Comment: i have to make PDF's load in a slideshow format- do you think this can be done in a div?

Comment: Oh, no a PDF won't render in a div. I'm not sure which browsers it will render it or not actually. Is converting each PDF page into an image an option?

Comment: heh, i wish- the data in the PDF must stay editable at any time. we have a pretty archaic version that is generating the pdf's nicely in IE but 4 separate pages are needed for each slide in the slideshow (the pause button is actually a link to the same page which isnt in a metatag refresh loop).